# .NET CIL Call or CallVirt?

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, cil

How can I determine if a method needs to be called with "Call" or "Callvirt"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can follow these simple rules one by one to determine which you should use:

- Is the method `static`?  Then use `call`.
- Is the type you are invoking on a value type? Then use `call`. (This *does not* apply if the value is boxed -- then you are actually invoking on `object` or some interface, and those are reference types.)
- Is the method you are invoking declared `virtual` or `abstract`? Then use `callvirt`.
- Are you invoking the method through an interface reference? Then use `callvirt`.
- Is the method you are invoking declared `override`, but neither the method nor the declaring type declared `sealed`?  Then use `callvirt`.

In all other cases, no virtual dispatch is required so you *can* use `call` -- but you *should* use `callvirt`.  Here's why:

Using `callvirt` on non-virtual methods is equivalent to `call` except when the first argument is null.  In that case `callvirt` will throw a `NullReferenceException` immediately, whereas `call` will not.  This makes sense, because `callvirt` is intended to be used in cases where virtual method dispatch is desired, and you can't do virtual method dispatch if you don't have an object on which to do a vtable lookup.

Note that `callvirt` will still throw an exception if the first argument is null even if a vtable lookup isn't necessary!

Considering this information, using `callvirt` for all non-static method invocations on reference types (as the C# compiler does) may be preferable as it will cause a `NullReferenceException` immediately at the call site instead of sometime later when `this` gets used (explicitly or implicitly) inside of the method.

Comment: But .NET uses "call" when calling something like Point.X. From what I am reading apparently value type methods use "call".

Comment: Yes, because those methods are not virtual, so I would expect the output to use "call".  Read my answer again.  (Also, structs *cannot* have virtual members since they cannot be inherited.)

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. Just weird that reflection shows "IsVirtual" as true for struct methods.

Comment: @High, struct instances _do_ have virtual methods; the methods they inherit/override from Object.  However, those methods are only invoked virtually if you're referring to a struct through a boxed instance (as an Object).

Comment: @cdhowie, one important difference between call and callvirt is that call will not throw an exception if arg0 is null.  From a pure code emit perspective (no generating source), this is not a big deal, but from a compiler/debugger perspective, it's helpful to throw a Null Reference at the point of the call rather than arbitrarily deep inside when arg0 is finally used.

Comment: Interface methods and delegates do need to be called as virtual methods as well. Just to complete the answer.

Comment: @Lucero, the exception is if you call an implemented interface method directly through an instance of a value type, in which case you must use call, as callvirt is not valid until the value type has been boxed (either explicitly or implicitly through prefixing callvirt with 'constrained')

Comment: @Dan, true, but in the non-boxed case it isn't an interface call (really) but rather a call of a method which happens to implement an interface method as well.

Comment: It is not equivalent to `call` on non-virtual functions, `callvirt` performs a null check.

Comment: I spent some time today rewriting this answer to take into account the feedback from comments.  Let me know if I left anything important out.

Answer (score 6):

By default, the C# compiler always uses callvirt for everything except static or value type calls.  This causes implicit null checking of the 'this' (arg0) argument.  You're not strictly required to follow this convention, but any virtual method on a reference type will definitely require callvirt.

Comment: Except for virtual methods on sealed classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you use call in a dynamicmethod on a virtual method the runtime throws a security exception.